# AWS - has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I used visual studio net 2.1 and a local sql database for my site on AWS. The first page comes up but when I try to put in a comment and the code routes to another page on my site I get this console error and the page is not routed to in the browser:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https...' from origin 'https://www.....dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is the startup.cs file

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                       );
            });

           app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Comment: I'm unclear to what resource your XMLHttpRequest is going to, but wherever `'https...'` is , that's where the cors needs to explicitly allow `'https://www.....dev'`

Comment: XMLHttpRequest  is the endpoint on the AWS for my serverless back end.

Answer (score 2):

For some CORS requests, the browser sends an additional OPTIONS request before making the actual request. This request is called a preflight request. The browser can skip the preflight request if all the following conditions are true:

1. The request method is GET, HEAD, or POST.
2. The app doesn't set request headers other than Accept, Accept-Language, Content- 
   Language, Content-Type, or Last-Event-ID.
3. The Content-Type header, if set, has one of the following values: 
   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   multipart/form-data
   text/plain

AllowAnyOrigin affects preflight requests and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

The preflight request uses the HTTP OPTIONS method. It may include the following headers:

Access-Control-Request-Method: The HTTP method that will be used for the actual request.
Access-Control-Request-Headers: A list of request headers that the app sets on the actual request.
Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Try allowing specific origins, methods and headers.
For more information can check the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#preflight-requests

Comment: I am using, .AllowAnyHeader() and  .AllowAnyMethod() so this should work. It may be related to AWS

Answer (score 0):

THe answer is to enable the api-gateway in AWS

In API Gateway Console click the Actions dropdown and select Deploy API.

This eliminated the CORS issue.